FXMLLoader setController vs setControllerFactory
In JavaFX, the FXMLLoader automatically creates the specified controller in an .fxml file using 0-arg constructor. It also provides methods to set/create the controller manually using FXMLLoader#setController or FXMLoader#setControllerFactory.
My question now is what is the difference between them? Are there situation where one is better than the other?
The documentation of both methods don't really answer my question.

This answer examines using a controller factory—among other approaches—in a particular context. I may help to focus your question on your intended use case.

The controller factory is an object that creates controller instances for you from a controller class (specified in the FXML file in the same way you do using the default approach). You can implement the factory any way you want (eg by calling a specific constructor and providing an argument, or referencing a DI framework, etc). Calling setController(…) just directly specifies the controller instance to use. In that case you must not specify the controller class in the FXML.

In other words setting the controller factory customises the default mechanism of creating a controller. The controller is still created by the FXMLLoader given the class specified in the FXML, but you are telling it how to create it. Calling setController() replaces the default mechanism completely.

When you load an FXML file with one of the load(...) methods defined in FXMLLoader, in the default setup two important objects are created by the FXMLLoader:

The root, which corresponds to the root element of the FXML structure
The controller, which is an object (a specific instance) connected to the root in various ways by the FXMLLoader.

Because you can't specify an actual object with a string value of an XML attribute (i.e. the value provided to fx:controller="..."), the default way this works is to specify the name of the controller class in the fx:controller attribute. By default, the FXMLLoader creates the controller instance by reflectively invoking the zero-argument constructor of the specified class.
The FXMLLoader injects @FXML-annotated elements from the FXML file into matching fields in the controller instance it has created. After this is done, it calls the initialize() method, if there is one, allowing fairly intuitive initialization of the controller and properties of the associated view.
Some consequences of this are worth noting (not all of which are relevant to this question):

If you call FXMLLoader.load(...) or its variants multiple times, multiple instances of the controller class will be created. This is (almost?) always what you want, but it's worth noting that state won't persist from one controller instance to another.
If the controller class does not have a zero-argument constructor, an error will be thrown. This error is necessarily thrown at runtime, as the compile cannot check the validity of the reflexive constructor call.

It is common to want to provide data in some form to the controller. For example, in MVC/MVP/MVVM-like architectures, the controller (or equivalent) often needs access to a model object. You can achieve this with the default setup by retrieving a reference to the controller after the FXML is loaded and passing it:
Model model = ...;

FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("path/to/view.fxml"));
Parent root = loader.load();
MyController controller = loader.getController();
controller.setModel(model);

While this approach is workable, it has several disadvantages:

The model is not provided until after the FXML is loaded, and consequently after the initialize() method is invoked. This means any initialization that has to be performed that depends on the model has to be done as a result of the setModel() call, and not in the more intuitive places (such as the initialize() method).
The model cannot be final in the controller class (which is usually natural and desirable), and there is no elegant way to enforce setting the model only once.
The controller class associated with the view is hardcoded in the code that loads the FXML, which arguably violates encapsulation of the view-controller pair.
The code is a little verbose.

The first two of these disadvantages can be remedied by calling setController(...) on the FXMLLoader prior to loading the FXML. However, this introduces new disadvantages of its own:
Model model = ... ;
MyController controller = new MyController(model);
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResources("path/to/view.fxml"));
loader.setController(controller);
Parent root = loader.load();

Note in this case, we are able to pass a model instance to the controller constructor. This means the model can be final, and is available as soon as the controller is instantiated. So the controller can look like:
public class MyController {

    private final Model model;

    @FXML
    private Label fooLabel;

    public MyController(Model model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        fooLabel.setText(model.getFoo());
    }
}

What happens when we call setController(...) is that we completely replace the default mechanism for creating a controller, instead providing a controller instance of our choosing. For this reason, we cannot now specify a fx:controller attribute in the FXML file; it would at best be redundant and possibly contradictory, and an exception will be thrown if we do.
The last two disadvantages above (verbosity and explicit connection in code between the view and controller class) still exist, though we have resolved the other two which are probably more important. However, not being able to specify the controller class in the FXML file means we introduce a new disadvantge:

Developer tools, such as SceneBuilder or your IDE, no longer have any way to determine the controller class being used for the FXML file. This means they can no longer highlight event handler method name or injected field name typos, or create stubs of those for us. This can be a pretty big disadvantage in terms of productivity.

By contrast, the controller factory allows us to use the default mechanism of creating a controller instance (i.e. specifying the class in the fx:controller attribute and letting the FXMLLoader provide the instance) but allows us to configure how the instance is created.
The controller factory is a Callback<Class<?>, Object>, which is essentially a function that maps a Class<?> (a type) to an object which will be used as a controller. It should be an instance of the provided class, but there is no actual check for that.
The previous example can be rewritten
Model model = ... ;
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("path/to/view.fxml"));
loader.setControllerFactory(type -> new MyController(model));
Parent root = loader.load();

In this case we can (and must) have fx:controller="com.example.MyController" in the FXML file. Our controller can look exactly the same as the previous version, with the final model instance which is accessible in the initialize() method. And our developer tools "know" which class is being used for the controller, so can check method and field names, etc.
Note we still hard-code the controller class name in our loading code. We can make a general controller factory using reflection. This implementation looks at the provided controller class, tries to find a constructor taking a model instance, and uses that constructor if there is one. If it doesn't find such a constructor, it tries to use the default no-argument constructor. If neither exist, an exception will be thrown. Obviously, the logic here is arbitrary and can be anything you choose.
Model model = ...;
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("path/to/view.fxml"));
loader.setControllerFactory(type -> {
    for (Constructor<?> constructor : type.getConstructors()) {
        if (constructor.getParameterCount() == 1 && constructor.getParameterTypes()[0].equals(Model.class)) {
            return constructor.newInstance(model);
        }
    }
    return type.getConstructor().newInstance();
});
Parent root = loader.load();

This is a bit more verbose, but we could write it once and reuse it across the application. The FXML files are "natural" and look exactly the same as in the default setup, and the controller can look like the one posted here (with a constructor taking a model instance, etc). There is arguably a general disadvantage of using reflection in terms of performance and lack of compile-time type checking, but the FXMLLoader is already using so much reflection the additional cost here is likely to be minimal.
One point worth noting is for nested FXML files, using <fx:include> in the FXML. The same controller factory will be used when the included FXML file is loaded as for the FXML file explicitly loaded that contains it. So if you use a controller factory, it must be flexible enough to provide the correct controller for both the "main" FXML and any included FXMLs.

If I remember correctly, the controller factory was introduced in version 2.1 in response to a request from someone wanting to use a dependency injection framework to manage JavaFX controllers. (It might have been Adam Bien, at the time he was writing the now-unmaintained afterburner framework, but my memory is not that good.)
Controller factories work nicely in this scenario. There are several Spring-JavaFX examples on this site, but the general idea is:
ApplicationContext context = ... ;

FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("path/to/view.fxml"));
loader.setControllerFactory(context::getBean);
Parent root = loader.load();

Essentially we just tell the FXMLLoader to get the controllers from the spring application context.
The Spring-based controller looks like
@Component(scope="prototype")
public class MyController {
    @Autowired
    private Model model;

    @FXML
    private Label fooLabel;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        fooLabel.setText(model.getFoo());
    }
}


Possible duplicate here: JavaFX: Need help understanding setControllerFactory
As explained in the duplicate, setControllerFactory is useful when you use a dependency injection framework and want to use your custom factory to inject dependencies. If you don't use any framework for dependency injection, it is easier to use setController.

Note though another advantage to using the controller factory is that it allows you (actually requires you) to specify the controller class in the FXML file. This allows tools and IDEs to check and even create event handler methods, @FXML annotations, etc. using setController() doesn’t let you use these aspects of the tooling.

@fi0x I am not sure if that really answers my question. Can't you use DI with both setControllerFactory and setController?

Lets take spring for example: If you need a bean in your controller, setController will always use the 0-args constructor of your controller and not set the bean. But if you're using a custom controller-factory, you can specify which constructor to use and inject the necessary beans. (At least that's how I understood the answer in my linked post)

“setController() will always use the 0-args constructor of your controller”. No, this is not true. By calling setController(…) you specify the actual controller instance, which you need to create in code (and can create any way you want).

@SquidXTV Yes, you could do setController(di.get(Foo.class)). But that has two disadvantages: (1) You can no longer define the controller in the FXML file and (2) it's somewhat less flexible. Using setControllerFactory(di::get) (or something similar) will work regardless of which controller is defined in the FXML file currently being loaded (assuming the DI framework is configured correctly). In my experience, it really only makes sense to use setController when you're using fx:root and both the root and the controller need to be the same instance.
